# SSIS package - wont run from SqlAgent but ok when run Manually

Tags: sql-server, encryption, authentication, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a SSIS package that references a remote database through an OLE DB connection to remote database. The connection is using a SqlServer account on the remote database and this all works fine.

When I enter the password in Visual Studio Package editor I have the "save password box" ticked, and it seems to write the encrypted password to the connection files. The test connection option works, and when I run the SSIS package it works.

When I build and deploy to SqlServer and run through a job, it fails. The job was initially running as a SqlServer Agent Account, but i also tried running this as my own account by setting up a credential and then a proxy. As I understand the encrypted password will only work for the user who encrypts it.

The job is owned by my own account, but have tried changing this a handful of times to. I don't think this affects the problem in regards to the error.

My error is as follows

> RemoteConnectionTester:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80040E4D Description: "Login failed for user 'xxxx'.".

The project protectionLevel is `EncryptSensativeWithUserKey`

Any tips or advice would be appreciated